# Check session and cookie not working in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies

I  have this code that makes sure your are logged in, and then making sure you are on the right page by checking a cookie set at login. This code works on a page in a directory underneath the login in script, however in a page in a directory below that it always takes you to accessdenied. Any ideas?

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
    header("location: http://mywebsite.com/member/accessdenied.html");
    exit();
}


 $_COOKIE["verify"] = $verify;
 if( $verify != file_get_contents("name.txt")) { 
  header("location: http://mywebsite.com/member/accessdenied.html");
 } else {  }

 ?>
```

And it seems like just the bottom part, the part that checks the cookie, isn't working. Again, any ideas?

Comment: Where does the $verify come from? Shouldn't that line be $verify = $_COOKIE["verify"]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have your cookie assignment backwards:

`$_COOKIE["verify"] = $verify;`

Should be

`$verify = $_COOKIE["verify"];`

And that should be:

`$verify = isset($_COOKIE["verify"])?$_COOKIE["verify"]:false;`

As if the cookie was not previously set, well it would give a notice error.

Comment: I tried this, however it still came up to accessdenied, and I checked the cookie was set at login.

Comment: Then I would try some debugging methods. IE: Echo out the file and echo out the cookie, make sure they are the same etc. And make sure the expected results are getting populated properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

 $verify = $_COOKIE["verify"];

 if( $verify == file_get_contents("name.txt")) { 
     echo $verify . 'is equal to the content of name.txt'
 } else {  
     echo $verify . 'is NOT equal to the content of name.txt'
 }

 ?>
```

Try debugging the code with this. See if the content of your variable is what you want. But I find it unusual that a **variable would be a file**.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you always get the content from file_get_contents? I could imagine it's found in one directory but not in the other!

Comment: yes, there is a copy of name.txt in both directories, thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

antoher idea: cookies can be set to be relevant for a particular directory only. I just realize, what we're missing here, is the part where you set the cookie in the first place.